# @DynamicInsert not recognized when using H2 database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I have a Spring Boot application. I use a Postgres database and want alternativly use a H2 database.

My sql schema looks like this

```
CREATE SEQUENCE car_id_seq START WITH 100;
CREATE TABLE car (
  id      INTEGER  DEFAULT nextval('car_id_seq')  PRIMARY KEY,
  name    VARCHAR  NOT NULL  UNIQUE,
  content  VARCHAR  NOT NULL
);
```

My Car Entity looks like this

```
@Entity @DynamicInsert @DynamicUpdate
@Getter @Setter //lombok
public class Car {
    @Column @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column private String name;
    @Column private String content;
}
```

Now I try to persist an instance. Using the Postgres-Db everything is fine. The key is that the insert statement must be called without the passing a value for the id. With logs enabled I can see this statement `insert into Car (name, content) values (?, ?)`.

Now when I change to H2 I'm very suprised to see that the exact same code produces following sql statement `insert into Car (name, content, id) values (?, ?, null)`. Here the id is passed with value `null`. This of course causes a `NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement` -exception.

Why is there a different behavior and how can I fix that @DynamicInsert (and @DynamicUpdate) is/are working.

PostgreSQL 9.5.3, com.h2database:h2:1.4.193, Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Hibernate 5.0.11.Final

Answer (score 0):

While debugging hibernate I realized that `@DynamicInsert` has no effect when it comes to the identifier column.

The important difference is at the call

```
dialect.getIdentityColumnSupport().getIdentityInsertString()
```

Here the PostgresDialect returns `null` and the H2Dialect returns `"null"`. I extended H2Dialect to and returned `null`. For my use-case everything now works.

Probably somebody is able to tell me, what the background is.